# PHP script is working but don't display the right things on my webpage

Tags: php, apache, arduino-esp32

I'm sending a value from an ESP32 to my apache webserver and stocking it in a MySQL database with a PHP script. My PHP script is very basic and seems to work because the value sent by the ESP32 is correctly stocked in my database. It should display "New Record created successfully" on my webpage but it doesn't.

Moreover, I'm getting the right payload on the serial monitor.

Thanks for your help!

ESP32 Code:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>

/************************* Wifi Prerequisites **************************/
const char* ssid = "*******";
const char* password = "********";

void wifiConnection(const char* ssid, const char* password);
/**********************************************************************/


/******************* HTTP Request Prerequisites ***********************/
String URL = "http://domain/test.php";
int http_code{};


int test_number{20};
String post_data;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  wifiConnection(ssid, password);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  post_data = "number=" + String(test_number);
  HTTPClient http;
  http.begin(URL);
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  http_code = http.POST(post_data);
  
  String payload = http.getString();

  Serial.print("URL : "); Serial.println(URL);
  Serial.print("Data: "); Serial.println(post_data);
  Serial.print("httpCode: "); Serial.println(http_code);
  Serial.print("Payload: "); Serial.println(payload);
  Serial.println("-----------------------------------------");
}

void wifiConnection(const char* ssid, const char* password){
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.print(ssid);

  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    Serial.print(".");
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    delay(1000);
  }

  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connected!");
}
```

Serial Monitor Output:
[Serial Monitor Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLVVp.png)

PHP Script:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";


$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if(!$conn){
  die("Connection failed" . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo "Database connection is OK<br>";

if(isset($_POST["number"])){
  $number = $_POST["number"];
  $sql = "INSERT INTO number (number) VALUES ($number);";
}



if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
  echo "New Record created successfully";
} else{
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Database:
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AqEl.png)

Webpage:[webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93wTs.png)

Comment: Why would your webpage show anything? Any output generated by the php code when you upload the data is sent back to the place which requested the upload- i.e. your esp script. If you then load the same php page into your browser that's a separate http request which doesn't contain the upload data, so it won't succeed. Since it displays _nothing_ I'd guess maybe it crashed but you haven't got php error reporting enabled. The logic in the php is a bit off-beam since it'll try to run a sql query even when nothing was posted and there isn't even a query defined

Comment: If you write a webpage which can show what has already been uploaded and exists in the database, that would probably make more sense

Comment: Oh okay i need a html file to display what i uploaded, right ? I thought the echo function could display on my webpage.

Comment: Yes but you're still missing the point, I think. That echo you've written will only display at the time when the script has just inserted a record into the database. That only happens when the esp code has sent data to the php script. When you call the php script again from your browser there is no uploading happening, so you will not see that message. Instead you need a different php script for the browser to use, which will run a SQL "SELECT" query and then display anything that the esp code has uploaded into the database

Answer (score 1):

You're sending a **POST** request via your ESP32 and your php works as intended.

But the browser is sending a **GET** request when it loads your web page. So your `if(isset($_POST["number"]))` statement is false. In this case the variable `$sql` is not even created...

Comment: Ok but I don't understand how my data can be correctly stocked in my database if my variable $sql is not created.

Comment: These are two separate scenarios: 1) Sending request from ESP - POST request - variable created. 2) Opening the page in the browser - GET request - variable not created.

Comment: @Manashap as i explained also in my comments there are two different http requests happening - one from the esp script and one from your browser. Only the esp code uploads any data